# Re-activating a Facebook App

Tags: facebook-apps

I want to know if it is possible to re-activate a Facebook App that has been previously disabled.

This is what happened:

We created a Facebook App and an iPhone App that connect to each other. After releasing our game to App Store, one of our programmers accidentally deleted the App from Facebook. Now players are shown a message saying the Facebook App does not exist.

We know this may not be possible, but still wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I work on the platform team at Facebook.

Unfortunately there isn't a standard way to do this since this isn't a situation that occurs often. However, I can imagine how painful this may be. If you could provide me with either of the following - the app namespace, canvas/connect URL for the app or the app ID, we may be able to help.

Comment: Hi Abhishek,
It is painful indeed =(
Our App ID is '195285317237126'
Any help you can provide us will be highly highly appreciated.

Comment: Restored now. Can you please check and let me know?

Comment: =DDD
Don't you know how much we appreciate what you did today. Anything we could do for you, just ask. The other programmed involved insists on wiring you half of his salary XD

That was nice of you, here at Mantiz Game Studios, we owe you one. Don't hesitate to let us know.

Sincerely,
Julio A. Sánchez